# How to draw a cloud shape in canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

**I want to create a Cloud shape in Canvas.**

When the user clicks anywhere on the canvas, it will create a cloud shape,.

The user should be able to drag the shape.

I have achieved rectangle and arrow draw in canvas using below code.
But I can't succeed to draw an arc.

```
 private void drawOnRectProjectedBitMap(ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > iv.getWidth() || y > iv.getHeight()) {
            //outside ImageView
            return;
        } else {
            int projectedX = (int) ((double) x * ((double) bm.getWidth() / (double) iv.getWidth()));
            int projectedY = (int) ((double) y * ((double) bm.getHeight() / (double) iv.getHeight()));

            //clear canvasDrawingPane
            canvasDrawingPane.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvasDrawingPane.drawRect(startPt.x, startPt.y, projectedX, projectedY, paint);
            imageDrawingPane.invalidate();
            textSource.setText(x + ":" + y + "/" + iv.getWidth() + " : " + iv.getHeight() + "\n" +
                    projectedX + " : " + projectedY + "/" + bm.getWidth() + " : " + bm.getHeight()
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't you use a cloud image for your requirement ?

Comment: @VivekMishra yes we can.but it will be dragable.

Comment: Yes image can be draggable and it will be easy approach i guess. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055292/android-drag-and-drop-imageview-ontouchlistener) and [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html)

Comment: draggable image is not a big deal at all

Comment: we have draw bitmap in canvas as a cloud image.but it will not draggble. because its draw in canvas.